# Linq query for left-join

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have 3 tables:

```
* UserSettingsType { general, UserSpecific)
* UserSettingsOption { Currency:general, Language:general, Location:Userspecific }
* UserSettingsValue { Currency:USD, Location:US }
```

If I run the `SQL` query:

```
select ust.Name Type, uso.Name Option, usv.Value Value from UserSettingOption uso 
 inner join UserSettingType ust on ust.Id = uso.Type_Id
 left join UserSettingValue usv on usv.Setting_Type_Id = uso.Id
```

output is:

```
Type         | Name      | Value
--------------------------------
General      | Currency  | USD
General      | Language  | NULL
UserSpecific | Location  | US
```

How can I convert the above in `Linq` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
var result = (form uso in Context.UserSettingOption
              join ust in Context.UserSettingType on uso.Type_Id equals ust.Id
              join usv in Context.UserSettingValue on uso.Id equals usv.Setting_Type_Id into tmpusv
              from lusv in tmpusv.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new
              {
                 Type = ust.Name, 
                 Option = uso.Name, 
                 Value = lusv != null ? lusv.Value : null
              }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think like this

```
var item=(from a in contex.usersettingoption
          from b in contex.usersettingtype.where(x=>x.id==a.Type_id).DefaultIfEmpty()
          from c in contex.usersettingvalue.where(x=>x.setting_Type_Id==a.id).DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new {b.Type,a.Name,c.value}).ToList()
```